# NextJS responsiveness acting up

Tags: next.js, mobile, media-queries, styled-components, responsiveness

i built a personal website with nextjs. its my first time using next. So far, its been a very frustrating experience. im dealing with my page loading styling and images extremely slowly, like 3 seconds after html loads, My major problem now is my site showing totally differently on different devices, ive asked a couple of people to check and it shows what i want on some but for some reason, on others including my phone, shows smth else, the font sizes are all out of place, alignment is off.

ive tried making it a static html site with output export and npm run build, added babelrc,registry and document files as suggested in the docs all to no effect. i thought next doesnt like styled components much hence the responsive issues but i tried starting all over with css modules but i redid a whole section to see if the responsiveness i expect and see on my dev tools would actualize on my phone but nothing.  i wouldn't bother so much but this is my portfolio, been stuck for weeks but finding it hard to move on despite being unproductive. This is my final resort, can anyone please help?

source code: https://github.com/kennielima/portfolio